# Use of 'tug open'

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if you guys could help me out with the use of 'tug open' in the following sentence :

> Bob and Peter tugged open the door.

Bob and Peter  = subject
Tugged = verb
the door = object of the verb

What is 'open' here?

Thanks

Comment: Part of the verb phrase “tugged open”.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how any analysis here deals with ***He tugged open the door = He pulled open the door = He pulled the door open*** (and went in). But whereas on the way out he could ***pull the door closed***, we don't seem to be able to say ***He pulled closed the door***. Strange asymmetry, that. Then there's the matter of ***He pulled the door to***, which I'm perfectly happy with (where ***to pull to = to close***), whereas ***He pulled to the door*** sounds completely nonsensical.

Comment: In 'Missi shot wide', 'wide' is indeterminate between an adverb (the off-target shooting being referenced) and a resultative adjective  (the resulting position of the ball, wide of the mark). However here I'd favour the resultative interpretation, [tugged] [the door] [{into} an open state], regarding 'open' as an adjective. Compare 'He shot the outlaw dead' (though I'll concede that there is more cohesiveness between _tug_ and _open_ than between _shoot_ and _dead_).

Comment: _Open_ is a particle in the phrasal verb _tug open_. But there is no phrasal verb _tug closed_. In general, adjectives formed from participles don't get used as phrasal verb particles.

Comment: Thanks sir John Lawler. Does it mean tug open is a phrasal verb?